# Jenkins DSL script - parent path not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-confuration-as-a-code

I'm using the `cloudbees-folder` plugin to organize the DSL job definitions in a folder structure. The structure of the repo is similar to this:

```
jobs/
  - dev/
    - other/
       - job1/
       - job2/
       - folder.yml (dsl)
    - web/
       - job1/
       - job2/
       - folder.yml (dsl)
  - test/
    - other/
       - job1/
       - job2/
       - folder.yml (dsl)
    - web/
       - job1/
       - job2/
       - folder.yml (dsl)
```

In the [Casc Pipeline Demo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/demos/jobs/pipeline.yaml) shows the parent `folder` script being configured as part of the pipepline job, however I'd like to separate the `folder` script in to a separate config as illustrated in my directory structure above. In each of the `dev` and `test` directories, there are about a dozen directories, all of which follow the same pattern and are created successfully. However the `web` directory does not have the `folder.yml` config picked up first. This results in the following fatal error

```
2022-09-27 18:51:42.807+0000 [id=42]    INFO    j.j.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement#createOrUpdateConfig: createOrUpdateConfig for test/web/job1
2022-09-27 18:51:42.825+0000 [id=42]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed ConfigurationAsCode.init
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslException: Could not create item, unknown parent path in "test/web/job1"
```

How can I guarantee the order of configs the `JenkinsJobManagement#createOrUpdateConfig` uses so that the folders are always created before the job configs in the subdirectories are executed?

I previously tried prefixing the `folder.yml` config name with numbers and underscores thinking there is some alphabetizing going on, but there doesn't seem to be a deterministic way the configs are being ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when copy/pasting a dsl config, I did not rename a jobname so the parent path truly wasn't created. ‍♂️

Comment: As they say, you saved my life, ha ha. This answer made me double-check my spelling, and I found a typo, too. :)